# Using Objective-C category to avoid compilation error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-category

I did something a little bit nasty today.

All of our view controllers inherit from two different parent view controllers, let's say XXXViewController and YYYViewController. XXXViewController in turn inherits from `TrackedUIViewController`, which is a class provided in the Google Analytics SDK so all your view controllers can inherit from it and easily track them.

YYYViewController however, inherits from a different type of view controller. Ah, and it's an open sourced piece of code that I really don't want to change.

What's the problem here? We cannot track any of the YYYViewController children because we can't access the methods provided in TrackedViewController, since they are private.

I don't want to modify the source provided in the Google Analytics SDK. So what did I do? Create a category that exposes those methods, just to avoid the compilation error.

The obvious downside to this is that the GA source code changes it may break, but it will be fairly easy to detect.

I was wondering what other problems I could be facing by doing this, and if you guys can think of a better approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go up in the inheritance chain of YYYViewController, see in turn what class it inherits from. If it's UIViewController, simply change that particular superclass to TrackedUIViewController in the source and you're fine to go.

Example for better understanding: suppose `YYYViewController` inherits from `ZZZViewController`, which in turn inherits from `UIViewController`. Now you can change the superclass of `ZZZViewController` from `UIViewController` to `TrackedUIViewController` - since `TrackedUIViewController` inherits from `UIViewController`, no functionality will be lost, but magically your whole `YYYViewController` class will become trackable.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: The problem is that this YYYViewController is an open source component that I would not want to modify :)

Comment: @frowing you can't really do this otherwise. See, changing the word `UIViewController` to `TrackableUIViewController` should not hurt. As I mentioned, you won't loose any functionality...

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned the biggest risk of using undocumented APIs: Changes to the API are beyond your control and may break your logic, for example if methods are removed/renamed, or their behavior stops matching your expectations.

From the purely technical point of view, I can see no further problems, since in Objective-C all methods are public. As long as they continue to exist, you may continue to call them.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the root problem is excessive subclassing. Keep view controller hierarchies shallow. Use composition instead of subclassing. If you must subclass ensure that functionality that a class provides can be turned on & off by it's subclasses.